# Which components are on the motherboard of a Acer V3-571G laptop?

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I have an Acer V3-571G, which is in warranty service right now and is about to have its motherboard changed. I am curious to know which components are integrated into the motherboard, so I would know which of them are going to be "refreshed".

Comment: Most of the components are integrated, its very likely, the entire motherboard will simply be replaced.  Only the memory will be saved.

Comment: @Ramhound often the CPU, and sometimes the GPU is removable as well

Comment: The GPU is integrated, that I know for sure. I was mostly wondering about the CPU.

Comment: @Ramhound All "V3-571G" models have Ivy Bridge i5/i7 CPUs, which are socketed. It's only with the fourth-generation Core processors, of the Haswell generation, that they started being soldered onto the motherboard. So, no, the CPU will not be replaced if the CPU is working fine and something on the motherboard is broken.

Comment: it's actually a **faulty** VGA port that needs to be replaced... shame how such a low-priority part requires the whole motherboard to be changed

Comment: @MarioStoilov Most likely, your old motherboard will be sent back to the manufacturer, the BIOS will be re-flashed for security reasons, they'll perform a number of checks on it, replace the VGA port, then send out the motherboard to another customer who has a problem with a component on their motherboard, as a warranty replacement ;) It's **very** unlikely that they'll simply throw the old one in the trash.

Comment: For the servicing shop it might turn out simpler/cheaper/faster to just take out the old board, slip a new one in and reconnect the disk. They can then worry about pieces that can be salvaged at leisure later. If at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The General Answer

#### (Independent of what make/model computer you have)

Here's how you can answer this question for yourself, without having to ask it on SuperUser:

1. Write down your laptop make and model.
2. Google Search for "Make Model teardown" or "Make Model maintenance manual" or "Make Model repair guide" and find a guide that shows you how to service the unit.
3. Make a note of each part that is removed in the guide. These parts are unlikely to be included in the replaced motherboard because they can be removed using hand tools and are not soldered onto the motherboard.

That's basically all there is to it. Of course, depending on the policy of the manufacturer and/or the warranty shop you're having it repaired at, they may opt to ship a warranty repair "kit", and the shop might be nice enough to install *all* of the kit components into your computer, even if you don't strictly need them to be replaced. The only way to know this is to ask the shop technician or manager for a list of exactly what was replaced.

In most cases, the manufacturer and the shop will try to replace the bare minimum of components to get the laptop fixed up and running. This is for obvious reasons: it saves money. But, *on occasion*, they may have a "spare" something, that either came with the kit, or they just had laying around, and decide to include it as a throw-in to try and retain your business. This is *entirely* dependent on the mood/whims of the technicians, and it is impossible to document ahead of time under which circumstances this is likely to happen.

---

### The Specific Answer

#### (For the Acer V3-571G)

Unfortunately that model number is *not specific enough* to know exactly what components you have, but the platform chipset should be the same regardless. Here are two possible configurations I was able to find online:

```
Intel Core i5 3230M
4GB DDR3 Memory 
500GB HDD
NVIDIA GeForce GT 730M
8X DVD-Super Multi Double-Layer Drive
```

or

```
Intel Core i7 3610QM
6GB DDR3 Memory
500GB HDD
GeForce GT 640M
8X DVD-Super Multi Double-Layer Drive
```

The following components are *definitely not* included as part of the motherboard:

- The DVD drive
- The CPU (because this is a socketed CPU, not a BGA CPU like the newer Haswells)
- The hard drive
- The voltage regulator (this is inside the CPU, not on the motherboard, for Ivy Bridge)
- The display controller (the logic unit that controls the display panel)
- The RAM (this particular unit has replaceable RAM, but on smaller "ultrabook" devices, they are starting to solder the RAM onto the motherboard!)
- The WiFi/Bluetooth adapter (this particular unit has a replaceable WiFi card, but on smaller "ultrabook" devices, they are starting to solder the WiFi chipset onto the motherboard!)
- The keyboard
- The trackpad
- The outer chassis
- The display/LCD itself
- the Intel iGPU (because an Ivy Bridge iGPU is built into the processor and has no components on the motherboard)

The following components **are definitely** included as part of the motherboard:

- The audio controller
- The ethernet controller (if your device has ethernet at all, I didn't check)
- The Platform Controller Hub (PCH)
- The USB controller(s)
- The Nvidia GPU

The following components *may or may not* be included as part of the motherboard, depending on how the device was designed and the replacement policy (these things may come as part of the motherboard replacement "kit" that the manufacturer installs, depending on policy):

- The fans, if any
- The heatsinks, if any

At first there was a lot about this unit that was in the third category of me being "unsure" about whether it is part of the motherboard or not. But these uncertainties were resolved by [looking up a teardown/repair guide](http://www.laptopwide.com/news/2014/01/15/acer-aspire-v3-571g-disassembly-manual/) of the unit. You can clearly tell which parts are not part of the motherboard because the guy removes them from the unit. If they're part of the motherboard, they're soldered down and there's no removing them.

Note that if you are reading this and you have an "ultrabook" or tablet/laptop hybrid form factor device that is not the same as the unit the OP posted about, you may want to check the teardown guide for your specific device...

The [Microsoft Surface Pro](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Microsoft+Surface+Pro+Teardown/12842) has no user serviceable parts, and absolutely everything except the CPU is soldered onto the motherboard. Right now the general trend is that larger, bulkier devices tend to be more user-serviceable and more modular, while smaller, more compact and denser devices tend to be less user-serviceable, and more components are hard-wired to the motherboard and can't be removed.

Comment: A very good answer, sir. FYI, it's the i7 model

Comment: A colleague used to work repairing circuit cards.  That hasn't been done for a long time now, a new board is cheaper than the engineer's time in diagnosing, fixing, checking; and the result is probable to break down soon.